# E/SQLiteLog: (1) duplicate column name: Temperatur

Tags: duplicates

I just started to work with android studio. i am also new in the programming of apps or anything else. Now i try to build my first app. i get the failure massage: "E/SQLiteLog: (1) duplicate column name: Temperatur"

In the other Threads i don´t find the right solution.

My Code:

public class FangbuchDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DB_NAME = "fangbuch.db";
public static final int DB_Version = 1;

public static final String TABLE_KARPFEN = "Karpfen";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_DATUM = "Datum";
public static final String COLUMN_ZEIT = "Uhrzeit";
public static final String COLUMN_WINDRICHTUNG = "Windrichtung";
public static final String COLUMN_WINDSTAERKE = "Windstärke bft";
public static final String COLUMN_TEMPERATURA = "Temperatur außen";
public static final String COLUMN_TEMPERATURW = "Temperatur Wasser";
public static final String COLUMN_HPAGESTERN = "hPa gestern";
public static final String COLUMN_HPAHEUTE = "hPa heute";
public static final String COLUMN_HPAMORGEN = "hPa morgen";
public static final String COLUMN_MOND = "Mond";
public static final String COLUMN_GEWICHT = "Gewicht";
public static final String COLUMN_FOTO = "Foto";

public static final String TABLE_MEERFORELLE = "Meerforelle";
public static final String COLUMN_ID2 = "id2";
public static final String COLUMN_DATUM2 = "Datum2";
public static final String COLUMN_ZEIT2 = "Zeit2";
public static final String COLUMN_WASSERSTAND = "Wasserstand";
public static final String COLUMN_WINDSTAERKE2 = "Windstärke2 bft";
public static final String COLUMN_WINDRICHTUNG2 = "Windrichtung2";
public static final String COLUMN_TEMPERATURW2 = "Wassertemperatur";
public static final String COLUMN_STROEMUNG = "Strömung";
public static final String COLUMN_FOTO2 = "Foto2";

public static final String SQL_CREATE =
        "create table " + TABLE_KARPFEN + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key , " +
                COLUMN_DATUM + " text not null, " +
                COLUMN_ZEIT + " text, " +
                COLUMN_WINDRICHTUNG + " text, " +
                COLUMN_WINDSTAERKE + " integer, " +
                COLUMN_TEMPERATURA + " integer, " +
                COLUMN_TEMPERATURW + " integer not null, " +
                COLUMN_HPAGESTERN + " integer, " +
                COLUMN_HPAHEUTE + " integer, " +
                COLUMN_HPAMORGEN + " integer, " +
                COLUMN_MOND + " text, " +
                COLUMN_GEWICHT + " REAL, " +
                COLUMN_FOTO + " text); ";
public static final String SQL_CREATE2 =
        "create table " + TABLE_MEERFORELLE + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID2 + " integer, " +
                COLUMN_DATUM2 + " text not null, " +
                COLUMN_ZEIT2 + " text, " +
                COLUMN_WASSERSTAND + " text, " +
                COLUMN_WINDSTAERKE2 + "integer, " +
                COLUMN_WINDRICHTUNG2 + " text, " +
                COLUMN_TEMPERATURW2 + " integer, " +
                COLUMN_STROEMUNG + " text, " +
                COLUMN_FOTO2 + " text); ";


public FangbuchDbHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_Version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE2);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(FangbuchDbHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + "to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

At the beginning i had duplicate column names. But now i have changed this.
But i still get this message.

Whats my mistake? Can someone help me? Thanks

Regards Ulf

Comment: Have you tried to remove app and reinstall? If no, after change of column you have still `DB_Version` = 1. Change to 2, to make upgrade of DB to new column names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQL(ite) expert, but it's noticeable that your column names `Temperatur außen` and `Temperatur Wasser` contain a space and are inserted unquoted in the `create table` statement, which presumably causes the error. According to [*SQLite Keywords*](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), there are three or four ways of quoting an identifier in SQLite - you may want to choose one for the definitions of `COLUMN_TEMPERATURA` and `COLUMN_TEMPERATURW`.

Comment: now i have delete the spaces. but now i get the following failure:E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: TABLE_KARPFEN

Comment: I don't think that this error originates from the code shown in the question.

Comment: shall i show more code? i dont know exactly which code part you will need. i have 3 activities for the db configuration

Comment: You showed the right _activity:

public class DbDataSource_ (although this is, strictly speaking, a different question); there are three places where you used the name `"TABLE_KARPFEN"`, but you forgot that `TABLE_KARPFEN` is a string variable and not a literal name, so you have to use `TABLE_KARPFEN` or `"Karpfen"`.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this activities can help:

```
public class DbEntry {
//Karpfen Spalten Variablen
private long id;
private String Datum;
private String Zeit;
private String Windrichtung;
private int Windstaerke;
private int TemperaturA;
private int TemperaturW;
private int hPaGestern;
private int hPaHeute;
private int hPaMorgen;
private String Mond;
private float Gewicht;

//Meerforellen Spalten Variablen
private long id2;
private String Datum2;
private String Zeit2;
private String Wasserstand;
private int Windstaerke2;
private String Windrichtung2;
private int TemperaturW2;
private String Stroemung;

//get und set für Karpfentabelle
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId (long id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDatum() {
    return Datum;
}
public void setDatum(String string) {
    this.Datum = Datum;
}

public String getZeit() {
    return Zeit;
}
public void setZeit(String string) {
    this.Zeit = Zeit;
}

public String getWindrichtung() {
    return Windrichtung;
}
public void setWindrichtung(String string) {
    this.Windrichtung =  Windrichtung;
}

public int getWindstaerke() {
    return Windstaerke;
}
public void setWindstaerke(int anInt) {
    this.Windstaerke = Windstaerke;
}

public int getTemperaturA() {
    return TemperaturA;
}
public void setTemperaturA(int anInt) {
    this.TemperaturA = TemperaturA;
}

public int getTemperaturW() {
    return TemperaturW;
}
public void setTemperaturW(int anInt) {
    this.TemperaturW = TemperaturW;
}

public int gethPaGestern() {
    return hPaGestern;
}
public void sethPaGestern(int anInt) {
    this.hPaGestern = hPaGestern;
}

public int gethPaHeute() {
    return hPaHeute;
}
public void sethPaHeute(int anInt) {
    this.hPaHeute = hPaHeute;
}

public int gethPaMorgen() {
    return hPaMorgen;
}
public void sethPaMorgen(int anInt) {
    this.hPaMorgen = hPaMorgen;
}

public String getMond() {
    return Mond;
}
public void setMond(String string) {
    this.Mond = Mond;
}

public float getGewicht() {
    return Gewicht;
}
public void setGewicht(float aFloat) {
    this.Gewicht = Gewicht;
}

//get und set für Meerforellen Tabelle
public long getId2() {
    return id2;
}
public void setId2(long aLong) {
    this.id2 = id2;
}

public String getDatum2() {
    return Datum2;
}
public void setDatum2(String string) {
    this.Datum2 = Datum2;
}

public String getZeit2() {
    return Zeit2;
}
public void setZeit2(String string) {
    this.Zeit2 = Zeit2;
}

public String getWasserstand() {
    return Wasserstand;
}
public void setWasserstand(String string) {
    this.Wasserstand = Wasserstand;
}

public int getWindstaerke2() {
    return Windstaerke2;
}
public void setWindstaerke2(int anInt) {
    this.Windstaerke2 = Windstaerke2;
}

public String getWindrichtung2() {
    return Windrichtung2;
}
public void setWindrichtung2(String string) {
    this.Windrichtung2 = Windrichtung2;
}

public int getTemperaturW2() {
    return TemperaturW2;
}
public void setTemperaturW2(int anInt) {
    this.TemperaturW2 = TemperaturW2;
}

public String getStroemung() {
    return Stroemung;
}
public void setStroemung(String string) {
    this.Stroemung = Stroemung;
}
```

}

or this activity:

public class DbDataSource {

```
private SQLiteDatabase fbDatabase;
private FangbuchDbHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumnsKarpfen = {"COLUMN_ID", "COLUMN_DATUM", "COLUMN_ZEIT", "COLUMN_WINDRICHTUNG", "COLUMN_WINDSTAERKE",
        "COLUMN_TEMPERATURA", "COLUMN_TEMPERATURW", "COLUMN_HPAGESTERN", "COLUMN_HPAHEUTE", "COLUMN_HPAMORGEN", "COLUMN_MOND",
        "COLUMN_GEWICHT"};
private String[] allColumnsMeerforelle = {"COLUMN_ID2", "COLUMN_DATUM2", "COLUMN_ZEIT2", "COLUMN_WASSERSTAND", "COLUMN_WINDSTAERKE2",
        "COLUMN_WINDRICHTUNG2", "COLUMN_TEMPERATURW2", "COLUMN_STROEMUNG"};

public DbDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new FangbuchDbHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    fbDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public DbEntry createEntryKarpfen(String Datum, String Zeit, String Windrichtung, int Windstaerke, int TemperaturA, int TemperaturW,
                                    int hPaGestern, int hPaHeute, int hPaMorgen, String Mond, float Gewicht) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("COLUMN_DATUM", Datum);
    values.put("COLUMN_ZEIT", Zeit);
    values.put("COLUMN_WINDRICHTUNG", Windrichtung);
    values.put("COLUMN_WINDSTAERKE", Windstaerke);
    values.put("COLUMN_TEMPERATURA", TemperaturA);
    values.put("COLUMN_TEMPERATURW", TemperaturW);
    values.put("COLUMN_HPAGESTERN", hPaGestern);
    values.put("COLUMN_HPAHEUTE", hPaHeute);
    values.put("COLUMN_HPAMORGEN", hPaMorgen);
    values.put("COLUMN_MOND", Mond);
    values.put("COLUMN_GEWICHT", Gewicht);

    long insertId = fbDatabase.insert("TABLE_KARPFEN", null, values);

    Cursor cursor = fbDatabase.query("TABLE_KARPFEN", allColumnsKarpfen, "COLUMN_ID = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursorToDbEntryKarpfen(cursor);

}

public DbEntry createEntryMeerforelle(String Datum2, String Zeit2, String Wasserstand, int Windstaerke2, String Windrichtung2, int TemperaturW2,
                                 String Stroemung) {
    ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
    values2.put("COLUMN_DATUM2", Datum2);
    values2.put("COLUMN_ZEIT2", Zeit2);
    values2.put("COLUMN_WASSERSTAND", Wasserstand);
    values2.put("COLUMN_WINDSTAERKE2", Windstaerke2);
    values2.put("COLUMN_WINDRICHTUNG2", Windrichtung2);
    values2.put("COLUMN_TEMPERATURW2", TemperaturW2);
    values2.put("COLUMN_STROEMUNG", Stroemung);

    long insertId2 = fbDatabase.insert("TABLE_MEERFORELLE", null, values2);

    Cursor cursorMeerforelle = fbDatabase.query("TABLE_MEERFORELLE", allColumnsMeerforelle, "COLUMN_ID2 = " + insertId2, null, null, null, null);
    cursorMeerforelle.moveToFirst();
    return cursorToDbEntryMeerforelle(cursorMeerforelle);

}

protected List<DbEntry> getKarpfenEntries() {
    List<DbEntry> EntryKarpfenList = new ArrayList<DbEntry>();
    EntryKarpfenList = new ArrayList<DbEntry>();

    Cursor cursor = fbDatabase.query("TABLE_KARPFEN", allColumnsKarpfen, null,null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if(cursor.getCount() == 0) return EntryKarpfenList;

    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        DbEntry entry = cursorToDbEntryKarpfen(cursor);
        EntryKarpfenList.add(entry);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return EntryKarpfenList;
}


protected List<DbEntry> getMeerforelleEntries() {
    List<DbEntry> EntryMeerforelleList = new ArrayList<DbEntry>();
    EntryMeerforelleList = new ArrayList<DbEntry>();

    Cursor cursor = fbDatabase.query("TABLE_MEERFORELLE", allColumnsMeerforelle, null,null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if(cursor.getCount() == 0) return EntryMeerforelleList;

    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        DbEntry entry = cursorToDbEntryKarpfen(cursor);
        EntryMeerforelleList.add(entry);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return EntryMeerforelleList;
}


private DbEntry cursorToDbEntryKarpfen(Cursor cursor) {
    DbEntry entry = new DbEntry();
    entry.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    entry.setDatum(cursor.getString(1));
    entry.setZeit(cursor.getString(2));
    entry.setWindrichtung(cursor.getString(3));
    entry.setWindstaerke(cursor.getInt(4));
    entry.setTemperaturA(cursor.getInt(5));
    entry.setTemperaturW(cursor.getInt(6));
    entry.sethPaGestern(cursor.getInt(7));
    entry.sethPaHeute(cursor.getInt(8));
    entry.sethPaMorgen(cursor.getInt(9));
    entry.setMond(cursor.getString(10));
    entry.setGewicht(cursor.getFloat(11));

    return entry;
}


private DbEntry cursorToDbEntryMeerforelle(Cursor cursor) {
    DbEntry entry2 = new DbEntry();
    entry2.setId2(cursor.getLong(0));
    entry2.setDatum2(cursor.getString(1));
    entry2.setZeit2(cursor.getString(2));
    entry2.setWasserstand(cursor.getString(3));
    entry2.setWindstaerke2(cursor.getInt(4));
    entry2.setWindrichtung2(cursor.getString(5));
    entry2.setTemperaturW2(cursor.getInt(6));
    entry2.setStroemung(cursor.getString(7));

    return entry2;

}
```

}